# Component doesn't render within child route in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular9

Here's my `app.component.html`:

```html
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
```

and `sidenav.component.html`:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="some-class">
    <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">
        ...
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

`app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full', },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, },
  { path: 'admin', redirectTo: '/admin/users', pathMatch: 'full', },
  { path: 'admin', children: [{
      path: 'permissions', component: PermissionsComponent, }, {
      path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, },]},
];
```

and one of the route components is `UsersComponent` and has the following template:

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <h1 class="headline">Administration</h1>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">
    ...
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <p>users works!</p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

and this works as expected up until here. But when I create a new component (say `inner-sidenav` with the following template (from `UsersComponent`):

```html
<mat-sidenav opened mode="side">
  ...
</mat-sidenav>
```

and update `UsersComponent`'s template to:

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <h1 class="headline">Administration</h1>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container>
    <app-inner-sidenav></app-inner-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <p>users works!</p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

the inner `mat-sidenav` (that should be rendered in place of `app-inner-sidebar`) doesn't render at all. What am I missing?

**Update:**

To replicate the issue, please visit [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-51qyne).

Comment: Do you see errors in the console? Is the `inner-sidenav` component included in the module just like `UsersComponent`?

Comment: No errors in the console. And `InnerSidenavComponent` is included in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Can you upload to StackBlitz?

Comment: @Benny Updated the question with StackBlitz reference. Thanks, appreciated!

Comment: After examining your StackBlitz project see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hasan the reason is the nesting rules of Material Sidenav.
You can't have a "foreign" element as a direct child of `<mat-sidenav-container>` (much like `<table>` can only have `<thead>, <tbody>, <tr>` as direct children).

Instead, **Users** components markup should be:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">
      <app-inner-sidenav></app-inner-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <p>users works!</p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

And **Inner Navbar** component markup should be:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/users']">Users</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the case!

Answer (score 0):

When you have `<mat-sidenav-content>` inside `<mat-sidenav-container>` you cannot add custom html inside `<mat-sidenav-container>`. Instead you have to add your  `<app-inner-sidenav>` inside `<mat-sidenav-content>`.

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">
    <a [routerLink]="['/admin/users']">Users hehe</a>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <app-inner-sidenav></app-inner-sidenav>
    <p>users works!</p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

or you can remove `<mat-sidenav-content>` like this

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">
        <a [routerLink]="['/admin/users']">Users hehe</a>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <app-inner-sidenav></app-inner-sidenav>
    <p>users works!</p>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: I didn't quite get, but this was not the case. See the accepted answer, thanks.